# What's wrong with the fading of this TikZ node's shadow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm trying to add a shadow with a faded edge to nodes.  With the following document I only get a grey circle, with a hard edge, slightly below right of the node.  This is a snippet form my code.  What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fadings}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, transform shape]
         \node[circle,fill=white,draw=black,thick,preaction={fill=black,opacity=.3,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm,path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 20 percent}}] (1) at (0,0) {1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always provide full minimal documents not just snippets. Especially with TikZ/PGF which has many extra libraries. This way all what we have to do is Copy&Paste to run the example. Also you should state what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: @MartinScharrer thanks for the advice, I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks, but keep in mind that it is supposed to be a *minimal* example. Avoid all non-essential code, like title and author as well as unrated packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 20 percent` must be in the argument `preaction` but outside of the there included `transform canvas`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
 \node[circle,fill=white,draw=black,thick,
       preaction={
         fill=black,opacity=.3,
         path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 20 percent,
         transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}
       }] (1) at (0,0) {1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*Result:*

(The fading isn't fully preserved by PDF->PNG and downscaling)

[image: Result]

Comment: @MartinScharrer If I compile your code I only get the node without a shadow.

Comment: @Zoran: That's funny, it works on my PC. I just tested it again. However it only works with `pdflatex`, with DVI/PS output I get no shading but the shadow is black. Could you post your flavor and version of latex and tikz please.

Comment: @MartinScharrer the output of `pdflatex --verison` is `pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.11-2.2 (TeX Live 2010/Arch Linux)` I don't really know how to get the version of latex and tikz, though.

Comment: @Zoran: Thats the latex version I was talking about (the executable, not the format which is LaTeX2e). The TikZ version can be printed by adding `\listfiles` just above `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: There is no version in the tikz.code.tex line. `pgfsys.sty`'s version is `2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)`.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @Zoran: Which pdf viewer are you using?

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I'm using Evince.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I opened the pdf in Adobe Reader on a Windows box and there it is ok.  Seems to be a bug in Evince.

Comment: @Zoran: Yes evince seems to be [unable to render shadings](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/644135).

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Yes found that one, too.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: This technique doesn't really work for rectangular nodes. Any hints on that? We don't have a "rectangle with fuzzy edge 20 percent" path fading.

Comment: @recluze: Sorry, I can't help you with this. I don't do much with fadings myself.