# How do I add a soft/fuzzy/gradient drop shadow to a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Faded drop-shadow using tikz-based rounded rectangle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11272/faded-drop-shadow-using-tikz-based-rounded-rectangle)

I would like to add a soft drop shadow to this node (holding text):

```
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes,shadows,fadings,patterns,calc,positioning}%

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[shape=rectangle,fill=white,inner xsep=.5cm,inner ysep=.5cm,text width=5cm,text depth=1\textheight](box){Text goes here (actually, a minipage)};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I understand that I can add a simple drop-shadow simply adding the option `dropshadow`, but how do I make it fuzzy, and how do I control the radius of the fuzziness and the x,y offsets from the node 'box'?

I have tried to emulate the effect with a rectangle positioned to the right of the node, using the options `color=black,shape fading=east`, but it ends up completely transparent.

(Yes, I'm a complete tikz newbie.)

Comment: I think this question could be of interest to you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11272/faded-drop-shadow-using-tikz-based-rounded-rectangle

Comment: Fuzzy shadow is easy with circles but it's  a problem with rectangles. See the link given by Jake !

Comment: Please take a look at the questions that others have suggested as the answers there might help you. If they do, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find the answers quickly. If they don't, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: @Martin: Don't forget that we have this Building Block: If your question is closed and you still need help, don't worry, [here you'll find help on what to do next](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/my-question-was-closed-as-a-duplicate-but-i-still-need-help-what-can-i-do).