# How to add a transparent shadow to a block in beamer?

Tags: beamer, transparency, shadows

Here my attempt to add a shadow to a block:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% add a background image
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image}}

% use rounded blocks with shadow
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Block with shadow and with background image}

  \begin{block}{Block with shadow}
    Content...
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The (poor) result:

[image]

***The shadow hides my background!***

**Edit:** `beamer` offered this feature for some time, but [it is incompatible with the latex-dvips-ps2pdf route](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/161). I suppose this feature could be optional...

Comment: Do you want just the shadow to have transparency or the complete block?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Just the shadow... as a *real* shadow! ;-)

Comment: Some good considerations are in [Faded drop-shadow using tikz-based rounded rectangle?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11272/14500)

Comment: `beamer` offered this feature for some time, but [it is incompatible with the latex-dvips-ps2pdf route](https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/161/patch-real-transparency-for-box-shadows)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get real transparency for box shadows with beamer, you could use this [patch](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/1213789e682c695a5c6e44debe40ad0042764f8e) from the beamer repository. At this time, this patch is not included in beamer (see [discussion](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/161)).

If you use `pdflatex`, you can use the patched version of `beamerbaseboxes.sty`.

Here is the result of my MWE:

[image]

Here is the patched version of `beamerbaseboxes.sty` (*put it in the same directory as your beamer document to get real transparency*):

```
% Copyright 2003--2007 by Till Tantau
% Copyright 2010 by Vedran Mileti\'c
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%
% See the file doc/licenses/LICENSE for more details.

\def\beamerboxesdeclarecolorscheme#1#2#3{% scheme name, upper color, lower color
  \setbeamercolor{@scheme upper #1}{fg=white,bg={#2}}
  \setbeamercolor{@scheme lower #1}{bg={#3}}
}

\define@key{beamerboxes}{scheme}{\def\bmb@upper{@scheme upper #1}\def\bmb@lower{@scheme lower #1}}
\define@key{beamerboxes}{upper}{\def\bmb@upper{#1}}
\define@key{beamerboxes}{lower}{\def\bmb@lower{#1}}
\define@key{beamerboxes}{width}{\edef\bmb@width{#1}}
\define@key{beamerboxes}{shadow}[true]{\csname bmb@shadow#1\endcsname}

\newif\ifbmb@shadow
\newbox\bmb@box
\newbox\bmb@colorbox
\newdimen\bmb@boxwidth
\newdimen\bmb@boxheight
\newdimen\bmb@prevheight
\newdimen\bmb@temp
\newdimen\bmb@dima
\newdimen\bmb@dimb

\newcommand\beamerboxesrounded[2][]{%
  \global\let\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip=\relax%
  \vbox\bgroup%
  \setkeys{beamerboxes}{upper=block title,lower=block body,width=\textwidth,shadow=false}%
  \setkeys{beamerboxes}{#1}%
  {%
    \usebeamercolor{\bmb@lower}%
    \globalcolorstrue%
    \colorlet{lower.bg}{bg}%
  }%
  {%
    \usebeamercolor{\bmb@upper}%
    \globalcolorstrue%
    \colorlet{upper.bg}{bg}%
  }%
  %
  % Typeset head
  %
  \vskip4bp
  \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\bmb@width}%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{\bmb@upper}%
      #2%
    \end{minipage}}%
  \ifdim\wd\bmb@box=0pt%
    \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox{}%
    \ht\bmb@box=1.5pt%
    \bmb@prevheight=-4.5pt%
  \else%
    \wd\bmb@box=\bmb@width%
    \bmb@temp=\dp\bmb@box%
    \ifdim\bmb@temp<1.5pt%
      \bmb@temp=1.5pt%
    \fi%
    \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox{\raise\bmb@temp\hbox{\box\bmb@box}}%
    \dp\bmb@box=0pt%
    \bmb@prevheight=\ht\bmb@box%
  \fi%
  \bmb@temp=\bmb@width%
  \bmb@dima=\bmb@temp\advance\bmb@dima by2.2bp%
  \bmb@dimb=\bmb@temp\advance\bmb@dimb by4bp%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{0bp}{+-\ht\bmb@box}{0bp}{+-\ht\bmb@box}
      \ifdim\wd\bmb@box=0pt%
        \color{lower.bg}%
      \else%
        \color{upper.bg}%
      \fi%
      \pgfpathqmoveto{-4bp}{-1bp}
      \pgfpathqcurveto{-4bp}{1.2bp}{-2.2bp}{3bp}{0bp}{3bp}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{3bp}}
      \pgfpathcurveto%
      {\pgfpoint{\bmb@dima}{3bp}}%
      {\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{1.2bp}}%
      {\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{-1bp}}%
      \bmb@dima=-\ht\bmb@box%
      \advance\bmb@dima by-2pt%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-4bp}{\bmb@dima}}
      \pgfusepath{fill}
    \end{pgfpicture}%
    \copy\bmb@box%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-1pt%
  \ifdim\wd\bmb@box=0pt%
  \else%
    \hbox{%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\bmb@width}{6pt}
        \bmb@dima=\bmb@width%
        \advance\bmb@dima by8bp%
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{-4bp}{-1bp}}{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dima}{8bp}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        {%
          \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-4bp}{0bp}}%
          \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{bmb@transition}}%
        }%
      \end{pgfpicture}%
    }%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip-0.5pt%
  \fi%
  \setbox\bmb@colorbox=\hbox{{\pgfpicturetrue\pgfsetcolor{lower.bg}}}%
  \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox\bgroup\begin{minipage}[b]{\bmb@width}%
    \vskip2pt%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{\bmb@lower}%
    \colorlet{beamerstructure}{upper.bg}%
    \colorlet{structure}{upper.bg}%
    %\color{.}%
  }

\def\endbeamerboxesrounded{%
  \end{minipage}\egroup%
  \bmb@temp=\dp\bmb@box%
  \advance\bmb@temp by.5pt%
  \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox{\raise\bmb@temp\hbox{\box\bmb@box}}%
  \dp\bmb@box=0pt%
  \bmb@boxwidth=\bmb@width%
  \bmb@boxheight=\ht\bmb@box%
  \advance\bmb@boxheight by4bp%
  \advance\bmb@boxheight by\bmb@prevheight%
  \ifbmb@shadow%
    \pgfdeclareradialshading{bmb@shadowball}{\pgfpointorigin}
    {%
      color(0bp)=(pgftransparent!50);
      color(4bp)=(pgftransparent!100)
    }%
    \pgfdeclareradialshading{bmb@shadowballlarge}{\pgfpointorigin}
    {%
      color(0bp)=(pgftransparent!0);
      color(8bp)=(pgftransparent!100)
    }%
    \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{bmb@shadowhorz}{\bmb@boxheight-6bp}
    {%
      color(0bp)=(pgftransparent!0);
      color(8bp)=(pgftransparent!100)
    }%
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{bmb@shadowvert}{\bmb@boxwidth-4bp}
    {%
      color(0bp)=(pgftransparent!100);
      color(8bp)=(pgftransparent!0)
    }%
    \pgfdeclarefading{bmb@shadowmask}
    {%
      \begin{pgfpicture}
        \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{4bp}{4bp}]{\pgfuseshading{bmb@shadowball}}
        \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{\bmb@boxwidth}{8bp}]{\pgfuseshading{bmb@shadowballlarge}}
        \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{\bmb@boxwidth+4bp}{\bmb@boxheight+2bp}]{\pgfuseshading{bmb@shadowball}}
        \pgftext[left, at=\pgfpoint{4bp}{4bp}]{\pgfuseshading{bmb@shadowvert}}
        \pgftext[base, at=\pgfpoint{\bmb@boxwidth+4bp}{8bp}]{\pgfuseshading{bmb@shadowhorz}}
        %
        % clipping is needed because shadow is typeset on top of box
        \begin{pgfscope}
          \pgfsetcolor{black}
          \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{4bp}{8bp}}{\pgfpoint{\bmb@boxwidth-0.2bp}{\bmb@boxheight-2bp}}
          \pgfusepath{fill}
        \end{pgfscope}
      \end{pgfpicture}
    }%
  \fi%
  \bmb@temp=\bmb@width%
  \bmb@dima=\bmb@temp\advance\bmb@dima by2.2bp%
  \bmb@dimb=\bmb@temp\advance\bmb@dimb by4bp%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{0bp}{0bp}{0bp}{0bp}
      \ifbmb@shadow%
        \begin{pgfscope}
          \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{0bp}{-7bp}}
            {\pgfpoint{\bmb@boxwidth+8bp}{\bmb@boxheight+6bp}}
          \pgfsetfading{bmb@shadowmask}{%
            \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0.5\bmb@boxwidth+6bp}{0.5\bmb@boxheight-4bp}}}
          \pgfusepath{fill}
        \end{pgfscope}
      \fi%
      \unhbox\bmb@colorbox%
      \pgfpathqmoveto{-4bp}{1bp}
      \pgfpathqcurveto{-4bp}{-1.2bp}{-2.2bp}{-3bp}{0bp}{-3bp}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\the\bmb@temp}{-3bp}}
      \pgfpathcurveto%
      {\pgfpoint{\the\bmb@dima}{-3bp}}%
      {\pgfpoint{\the\bmb@dimb}{-1.2bp}}%
      {\pgfpoint{\the\bmb@dimb}{1bp}}%
      {
        \bmb@dima=\ht\bmb@box%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-4bp}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfusepath{fill}
      }
    \end{pgfpicture}%
    \box\bmb@box%
  }%
  \ifbmb@shadow%
    \vskip4bp minus 2bp%
  \else%
    \vskip2bp%
  \fi%
  \egroup% of \vbox\bgroup
}

%
% Shadings
%

\pgfdeclareverticalshading[lower.bg,upper.bg]{bmb@transition}{200cm}%
{%
  color(0pt)=(lower.bg);
  color(2pt)=(lower.bg);
  color(4pt)=(upper.bg)
}
```

Comment: Wow, nice! Was just wondering about this.

Answer (score 9):

A possible first approach, redefining `\beamerboxesrounded` and `\endbeamerboxesrounded` (as defined in `beamerbaseboxes.sty`) to use a change of opacity through `\pgfsetfillopacity`; the lines of code that were included are marked with  `% NEW`; the desired opacity can be changed using the `\opacity` command (initially set to `0.5`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\opacity{0.5}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\beamerboxesrounded[2][]{%
  \global\let\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip=\relax%
  \vbox\bgroup%
  \setkeys{beamerboxes}{upper=block title,lower=block body,width=\textwidth,shadow=false}%
  \setkeys{beamerboxes}{#1}%
  {%
    \usebeamercolor{\bmb@lower}%
    \globalcolorstrue%
    \colorlet{lower.bg}{bg}%
  }%
  {%
    \usebeamercolor{\bmb@upper}%
    \globalcolorstrue%
    \colorlet{upper.bg}{bg}%
  }%
  %
  % Typeset head
  %
  \vskip4bp
  \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\bmb@width}%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{\bmb@upper}%
      #2%
    \end{minipage}}%
  \ifdim\wd\bmb@box=0pt%
    \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox{}%
    \ht\bmb@box=1.5pt%
    \bmb@prevheight=-4.5pt%
  \else%
    \wd\bmb@box=\bmb@width%
    \bmb@temp=\dp\bmb@box%
    \ifdim\bmb@temp<1.5pt%
      \bmb@temp=1.5pt%
    \fi%
    \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox{\raise\bmb@temp\hbox{\box\bmb@box}}%
    \dp\bmb@box=0pt%
    \bmb@prevheight=\ht\bmb@box%
  \fi%
  \bmb@temp=\bmb@width%
  \bmb@dima=\bmb@temp\advance\bmb@dima by2.2bp%
  \bmb@dimb=\bmb@temp\advance\bmb@dimb by4bp%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{0bp}{+-\ht\bmb@box}{0bp}{+-\ht\bmb@box}
      \ifdim\wd\bmb@box=0pt%
        \color{lower.bg}%
      \else%
        \color{upper.bg}%
      \fi%
      \pgfpathqmoveto{-4bp}{-1bp}
      \pgfpathqcurveto{-4bp}{1.2bp}{-2.2bp}{3bp}{0bp}{3bp}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{3bp}}
      \pgfpathcurveto%
      {\pgfpoint{\bmb@dima}{3bp}}%
      {\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{1.2bp}}%
      {\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{-1bp}}%
      \bmb@dima=-\ht\bmb@box%
      \advance\bmb@dima by-2pt%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-4bp}{\bmb@dima}}
      \pgfusepath{fill}
    \end{pgfpicture}%
    \copy\bmb@box%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-1pt%
  \ifdim\wd\bmb@box=0pt%
  \else%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\bmb@width}{6pt}
      \bmb@dima=\bmb@width%
      \advance\bmb@dima by8bp%
      \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{-4bp}{-1bp}}{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dima}{8bp}}
      \pgfusepath{clip}
      {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-4bp}{0bp}}\pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{bmb@transition}}}%
    \end{pgfpicture}%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-0.5pt%
  \fi%
  \pgfsetfillopacity{\opacity}% NEW
  \ifbmb@shadow
    \setbox\bmb@boxshadow=\hbox{\pgfuseshading{bmb@shadow}}%
    \setbox\bmb@boxshadowball=\hbox{\pgfuseshading{bmb@shadowball}}%
    \setbox\bmb@boxshadowballlarge=\hbox{\pgfuseshading{bmb@shadowballlarge}}%
  \fi%
\setbox\bmb@colorbox=\hbox{{\pgfpicturetrue\pgfsetcolor{lower.bg}}}%
  \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox\bgroup\begin{minipage}[b]{\bmb@width}%
    \pgfsetfillopacity{1}% NEW
    \vskip2pt%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{\bmb@lower}%
    \colorlet{beamerstructure}{upper.bg}%
    \colorlet{structure}{upper.bg}%
    %\color{.}%
  }

\def\endbeamerboxesrounded{%
  \end{minipage}\egroup%
  \wd\bmb@box=\bmb@width%
  \bmb@temp=\dp\bmb@box%
  \advance\bmb@temp by.5pt%
  \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox{\raise\bmb@temp\hbox{\box\bmb@box}}%
  \dp\bmb@box=0pt%
  \bmb@temp=\wd\bmb@box%
  \bmb@dima=\bmb@temp\advance\bmb@dima by2.2bp%
  \bmb@dimb=\bmb@temp\advance\bmb@dimb by4bp%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{0bp}{0bp}{0bp}{0bp}
      \ifbmb@shadow%
      {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{4bp}{-3bp}}\pgftext{\copy\bmb@boxshadowball}}
      \begin{pgfscope}
        {%
\pgfsetfillopacity{1}% NEW
        \advance\bmb@temp by-1bp%
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{-7bp}}{\pgfpoint{9bp}{9bp}}%
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        }%
        {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{1bp}}\pgftext{\box\bmb@boxshadowballlarge}}
      \end{pgfscope}
      \begin{pgfscope}
      \pgfsetfillopacity{\opacity}% NEW
        \advance\bmb@temp by-4bp%
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{4bp}{-7bp}}{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{5bp}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{4bp}{-7bp}}\pgftext[left,base]{\copy\bmb@boxshadow}}%
      \end{pgfscope}
      \begin{pgfscope}
        \pgfsetfillopacity{\opacity}% NEW
        \advance\bmb@temp by 4bp%
        \bmb@dima=\ht\bmb@box%
        \advance\bmb@dima by\bmb@prevheight%
        \advance\bmb@dima by 4bp%
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{1bp}}{\pgfpoint{4bp}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \advance\bmb@dima by-4bp%
        {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{\bmb@dima}}\pgftext{\box\bmb@boxshadowball}}
        \advance\bmb@dima by-1bp%
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{1bp}}{\pgfpoint{4bp}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \advance\bmb@temp by4bp%
        {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{-3bp}}%
          \pgftransformrotate{90}%
          \pgftext[left,base]{\box\bmb@boxshadow}}%
      \end{pgfscope}
      \fi%
      \pgfsetfillopacity{1}% NEW
      \unhbox\bmb@colorbox%
      \pgfpathqmoveto{-4bp}{1bp}
      \pgfpathqcurveto{-4bp}{-1.2bp}{-2.2bp}{-3bp}{0bp}{-3bp}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\the\bmb@temp}{-3bp}}
      \pgfpathcurveto%
      {\pgfpoint{\the\bmb@dima}{-3bp}}%
      {\pgfpoint{\the\bmb@dimb}{-1.2bp}}%
      {\pgfpoint{\the\bmb@dimb}{1bp}}%
      {
      \bmb@dima=\ht\bmb@box%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-4bp}{\bmb@dima}}
      \pgfusepath{fill}
      }
      \ifbmb@shadow%
      {
        \color{black!50!bg}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{0pt}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{-.5bp}}
        \bmb@dima=\ht\bmb@box%
        \advance\bmb@dima by\bmb@prevheight%
        \advance\bmb@dima by 1bp%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \bmb@temp=\bmb@dima
        \advance\bmb@dima by 1bp%
        \color{black!31!bg}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@temp}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \advance\bmb@dima by 1bp%
        \advance\bmb@temp by 1bp%
        \color{black!19!bg}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@temp}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \advance\bmb@dima by 1bp%
        \advance\bmb@temp by 1bp%
        \color{black!6!bg}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@temp}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \advance\bmb@dima by 1.5bp%
        \advance\bmb@temp by 1bp%
        \color{bg}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@temp}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
      }
      \fi
    \end{pgfpicture}%
    \box\bmb@box%
  }%
  \ifbmb@shadow%
    \vskip4bp minus 2bp%
  \else%
    \vskip2bp%
  \fi%
  \egroup% of \vbox\bgroup
}
\makeatother

% background image
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]%
  \node at (current page) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
}

% blocks with shadow
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Block with shadow and with background image}

  \begin{block}{Block with shadow}
    Content...
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> This problem is fixed in beamer v. 3.51 (and only this version), see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/pull/469

Your code now gives the following output:

[image]

If you have another beamer version, try to place the following two files in your working directory:

- https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/d1d9094893ef705bc88ed60f64e4f83a1b1a6b85/base/beamerbaseboxes.sty
- https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/d1d9094893ef705bc88ed60f64e4f83a1b1a6b85/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemeshadow.sty

It won't work for dvi-based compilation chains.

---

**Edit:**

Since version v3.60 beamer again has native support for transparent shadows

Comment: Note: using these files will only work for PGF 3.1.5b or older. If your PGF is more recent, you'll have to downgrade. Older versions may be found here: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf.