# Latex beamer block shadow fades to white and not to the background color

Tags: beamer

I modified the background color using `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue!25}`. However, the shadow of the blocks fade from black to white and not to the background color (resulting in a tiny white stripe around the shadow before the background color takes over),  see code below.

I found the following fix
[How to add a transparent shadow to a block in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73960/how-to-add-a-transparent-shadow-to-a-block-in-beamer)

(there the white line around the shadow can also be seen clearly)

However, the modified version of `beamerbaseboxes.sty` seems to be outdated, since it changes the appearance of the whole presentation, not only the shadows. Since I do not want transparent shadows but merely shadows that fade into the background color, I would like to ask how to achieve this without hacking the `beamerbaseboxes.sty` file.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue!25}

\begin{document}

\frame{
  \begin{block}{test block} 
  block block
 \end{block}

}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code will give the expected output:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue!25}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareverticalshading[black,bg]{bmb@shadow}{200cm}{%
  color(0bp)=(blue!25); color(4bp)=(black!50!bg); color(8bp)=(black!50!bg)}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[black,bg]{bmb@shadowball}{\pgfpointorigin}{%
  color(0bp)=(black!50!bg); color(4bp)=(blue!25)}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[black,bg]{bmb@shadowballlarge}{\pgfpointorigin}{%
  color(0bp)=(black!50!bg); color(4bp)=(black!50!bg); color(8bp)=(blue!25)}
  %
   \makeatother

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{l}
  \begin{block}{in a block} 
  default font
 \end{block}
}

\end{document}
```

Please note: this is of course a hack to `beamerbasebox` since the original definitions are overwritten. I do not know if there could possibly be any side effects. (Those shadows could be used anywhere else...).  And of course i have no idea why it does not choose the background color automatically.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. Do you think this should be reported as a Bug to the beamer-developers?

Comment: Well if you do understand the code completely go on... I wouldn't claim that for me and therefore i could not write a qualified report. I'm still struggling in finding out how the color is actually chosen for the rounded  boxes.

Comment: If you dont feel qualified to write the bug report, I do neither :) Thank you again for the fix!

Answer (score 0):

[Since version v3.60](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/c38b336ac06bfdbcc2be52fbb0cbaac91384af4c), beamer now supports transparent shadows by default:

[image]