# Color of vertical shadow in frametitle, beamer, warsaw

Tags: beamer, color

I know that's its a common topic, but still I don't get it to work. I want a different background color (due to corporate design) and shadows which fade to that new color.

I have checked several threads, where the shadow is removed (that's not what i want) or where the shadow color is changed manually.

[Latex beamer block shadow fades to white and not to the background color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94577/latex-beamer-block-shadow-fades-to-white-and-not-to-the-background-color)

-> The solution has no effect on the title-shadow

[How to add a transparent shadow to a block in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73960/how-to-add-a-transparent-shadow-to-a-block-in-beamer)

-> I changed the beamerbaseboxes.sty, but it had no effect (I refreshed the FNDB and updated the formats after replacing the file)

My minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}{Nice Title}
       Stupid Content
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is (I added arrows to emphasize the shadow):
[image]

I expect the vertical shadow to start from black and end at yellow, like the background is.

Best regards,
karl.ranseier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug was fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/c7051f7003834fb06e40e97288de03f1364163f1 and is included in beamer v3.51 or v3.60 and newer

(the new transparent shadows had some problems, so they were temporarily disabled again for beamer v3.52-v3.59)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{\paperwidth}{%
        color(0pt)=(yellow);
        color(4pt)=(black!50!bg)    
    }
}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}{Nice Title}
       Stupid Content
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]