# How to change color of 'shadow' around frametitle (Latex beamer)

Tags: beamer, color, changes, shadows, frame-title

How do I change the blue shawdow around the frametitle to a different color?
Or rather even get rid of the shawdow

[image: screenshot of blue shadow around frametitle]

[Solution: I used the \setbeamercolor settings AFTER \begin{document}. Writing it before that solves the issue.]

Comment: Can you show us a small example that includes how you changed the colours?

Comment: And welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287584/36296 help?

Comment: Normally the shadow colour is determined by the colour of the title bar and the background colour. So I guess you are using some non-standard way to change the colour to green. In order to help you it would be really useful to know what you are doing.

Comment: Completing your code fragments to a compilable document I get the following output: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nLRnc.png I used Texlive2016 and `pdflatex`, `xetex` and `luatex` to compile. What are you using? Can you make your example complete, e.g. with `\begin{document}` etc.?

Answer (score 1):

With `Warsaw` you can modify the `topshade` colors.

```
\documentclass{beamer}%
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{bg=cyan!90}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=cyan!90}
\mode<presentation>
%\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow}
\definecolor{dgreen}{rgb}{0.,0.6,0.}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[frametitle.bg,frametitle right.bg]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{% Frametitle
    color(0pt)=(dgreen);
    color(\paperwidth)=(frametitle right.bg)}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{\paperwidth}{%
        color(4pt)=(blue);
        color(8pt)=(blue!50!bg)    
    }
}
\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A section}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Test test
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Test test
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Test test

        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\section{Another section}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Another section}
  Yes!  Test test
\end{frame}
\section{Final section}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Final section}
  No!  Test test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me, using Frankfurt.
Other appraches? I edited the question for more details.
Thank you, though!