# How to change after preamble the color a beamer's block shadow fades to?

Tags: beamer, color, backgrounds, shadows

Thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94580/18401), it is possible to make the shadow of a `beamer`'s block fade to the background color instead of white.

As pointed out by the following MWE, the problem is, the solution provided doesn't work after `\begin{document}`, which is annoying if one wants to change the background color in the middle of the document.

Hence the question: how to change after preamble the color a `beamer`'s block shadow fades to?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\newcommand{\test}[1][yellow]{%
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=#1}
  \makeatletter
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading[black,bg]{bmb@shadow}{200cm}{%
    color(0bp)=(#1); color(4bp)=(black!50!bg); color(8bp)=(black!50!bg)}
  \pgfdeclareradialshading[black,bg]{bmb@shadowball}{\pgfpointorigin}{%
    color(0bp)=(black!50!bg); color(4bp)=(#1)}
  \pgfdeclareradialshading[black,bg]{bmb@shadowballlarge}{\pgfpointorigin}{%
    color(0bp)=(black!50!bg); color(4bp)=(black!50!bg); color(8bp)=(#1)}
  %
  \makeatother
}

\test

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Foo}
    Bar
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
%
\test[cyan]
%
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Foo}
    Bar
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code from https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/pull/469 the shadow colour is automatically adapted:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Foo}
    Bar
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=cyan}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Foo}
    Bar
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I discovered [a strange phenomenon with this code](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/pull/469#issuecomment-374675879): combined with some fonts (e.g. from the `libertine` package), an extra rectangle is drawn (and slightly visible) between the box and its shadow.