# How do I get rid of the white background underneath my shadow?

Tags: beamer, theorems, backgrounds, shading

I have selected a specific background for my `beamer` slides and I am using the `theorem` environment for my theorems. When I turn the shadows on for the blocks however, instead of giving me nice shadows that blend in with the background, I get an ugly white space beneath the shadows. Does anyone know how I can get rid of this? Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames]{beamer} 
\usecolortheme[RGB={0,124,65}]{structure} 
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] 
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{gold.jpg}}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true] 
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[default]
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=dgr}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont={bf, color =dgr}]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}


\definecolor{dgr}{RGB}{0,93,49}%{0,62,32}%{1,80,43}%{25,96,15}%{13,68,30}
\definecolor{gr}{RGB}{1,99,52}%{40,78,54}%{152,50,34}%{19,98,43}
\definecolor{ot}{RGB}{100,31,69}
\definecolor{yy}{RGB}{230,208,115}

\setbeamercolor{block body}{use=structure,bg=yy}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=ot}
```

Comment: I looked at Paul's link. I have no idea how to use patches in latex. I am pretty much a beginner. Would anyone know a simpler/updated way to fix the problem or explain to me how to apply the patch? Thank you!

Comment: @Merry: As is suggested in [Paul's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86226/5764), create the file called `beamerbaseboxes.sty` and "put it in the same directory as your `beamer` document to get real transparency".

Comment: I'd like to report that I fixed this problem! I followed Paul Gaborit's comments on his link and found this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11272/faded-drop-shadow-using-tikz-based-rounded-rectangle  

As it turns out, if I don't use the pgf package (which I don't really need), it returns to its nicely shadowed state. Thanks for your help!