# Including an image with a faded border

Tags: graphics, transparency

I want to include an image. However, to make it blend in a little better, I'd like to add (overlay) a faded border that doesn't exist in the figure at the moment.

My attempt is to use [`transparent`](http://ctan.org/pkg/transparent) and a regular, thick-edge `\fbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{transparent,graphicx,xcolor}
\begin{document}

\noindent
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-10pt}%
 \setlength{\fboxrule}{10pt}% Rule will overlay with image
 \transparent{0.8}\color{white}% Rule is 50% white/transparent
 \fbox{%
   \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image}}%
}

\end{document}
```

This lacks serious pizazz. How can I do this using some transparency with a graphics package (or modify the `\fbox` construction to make it work)? Can I make the blend-in be gradual?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is an attempt with TikZ, using the `calc` and `fadings` libraries. The code is heavily inspired by some drop-shadow work done by [Caramdir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/83/caramdir) at [Faded drop-shadow using tikz-based rounded rectangle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11483/21344)

I defined a command `\framenode`, which accepts one optional and one mandatory argument:

```
\framenode[<frame-radius>]{<node>}
```

where `<frame-radius>` is the radius of the fade around the rectangle, as a dimension (default `10pt`), and `<node>` is the name of the node to frame.

The command only works on rectangular nodes. For the example, I've placed an image in a node called `image` with `inner sep=0` so the node tightly fits the image dimensions. Then I use

```
\framenode[15pt]{image}
```

to frame the node `image` with a fade of radius `15pt`.

**Update:** It turns out I made my life much harder than it needed to be. Much simplified code is posted now. The radial shading and clipping were both unnecessary because of the way `pgf` handles "pixel painting" when transparency is involved. There is a slight difference in the corners, but I don't think it's overly significant. It also avoids the viewer aliasing problems inherent in the first version.

**Complete Code:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade l,left color=transparent!100,right color=transparent!0]
\tikzfading[name=fade r,right color=transparent!100,left color=transparent!0]
\tikzfading[name=fade d,bottom color=transparent!100,top color=transparent!0]
\tikzfading[name=fade u,top color=transparent!100,bottom color=transparent!0]

% this "frames" a rectangle node
\newcommand\framenode[2][10pt]{
    \fill[white,path fading=fade u] (#2.south west) rectangle ($(#2.south east)+(0, #1)$);
    \fill[white,path fading=fade d] (#2.north west) rectangle ($(#2.north east)+(0,-#1)$);
    \fill[white,path fading=fade l] (#2.south east) rectangle ($(#2.north east)+(-#1,0)$);
    \fill[white,path fading=fade r] (#2.south west) rectangle ($(#2.north west)+( #1,0)$);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-a}};
    \framenode[15pt]{image} % opt. arg. is fade radius; mand. arg. is node name to frame
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Before (complex code)**
[image]

**After (simplified code)**
[image]

Comment: Which part of the code would I edit if I wanted a smaller faded margin? Would I be changing 100 to e.g. 500 in "\tikzfading[name=fade l,left color=transparent!100,right color=transparent!0]" ?

Comment: @ilamengl you shouldn't need to edit the fading to do that. Instead use the optional argument to `\framenode` instead: `\framenode[5pt]{nodetoframe}` and change `5pt` to any dimension you want to use for the margin.

Answer (score 4):

IMPROVED SOLUTION:

Here, I just overlay (nest) progressively clipped and regressively faded images atop each other. The outer image is unclipped and fully faded.  The successively overlaid images are governed by the invocation `\fadeimg{clip increment*.001}{reducing fade increment*.01}{image}`.  Overlays continue until fade drops to 0 (unfaded, full texture image).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,trimclip,ifthen}
\newcommand\IG[3]{%
  \clipbox{#1\width #1\height #1\width #1\height}{%
  \includegraphics[decodearray={#2 1 #2 1 #2 1},width=\textwidth]{#3}}}
\newcounter{clip}
\newcounter{fade}
\newcommand\fadeimg[3]{%
  \renewcommand\quietstack{T}%
  \setcounter{clip}{0}
  \setcounter{fade}{99}
  \calcfracs%
  \savebox\stackedbox{\IG{\clipfrac}{\fadefrac}{#3}}%
  \whiledo{\value{fade}>0}{%
    \addtocounter{clip}{#1}%
    \addtocounter{fade}{#2}%%
    \calcfracs%
    \savestack\tmp{\usebox{\stackedbox}}
    \savebox\stackedbox{\IG{\clipfrac}{\fadefrac}{#3}}%
    \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\usebox{\stackedbox}}{\tmp}%
    \ifnum\value{clip}>500\relax%
      \setcounter{fade}{0}%
    \fi%
  }%
  \noindent\usebox{\stackedbox}%
}
\def\calcfracs{%
  \ifnum\value{clip}>99%
    \xdef\clipfrac{.\theclip}%
  \else%
    \ifnum\value{clip}>9%
      \xdef\clipfrac{.0\theclip}%
    \else%
      \xdef\clipfrac{.00\theclip}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \ifnum\value{fade}>9%
    \xdef\fadefrac{.\thefade}%
  \else%
    \xdef\fadefrac{.0\thefade}%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\fadeimg{4}{-2}{everest}
\fadeimg{1}{-2}{everest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the use of

```
\fadeimg{4}{-2}{everest}
```

instead of

```
\fadeimg{2}{-1}{everest}
```

will give the same fade rate, but accomplish the task with 50 rather than 100 overlays.

Above base image from

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/IMG_2124_Everest.jpg

ORIGINAL SOLUTION (manual):

Here, I just overlay (nest) 6 progressively clipped images atop each other.  The largest (the inner most `\IG`) is only clipped 1.25% in size, but its color is most (85%) faded, using the `decodearray` feature of `\includegraphics`.  The image on top is clipped 7.5% in size, and is unfaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,trimclip}
\newsavebox\myimg
\newcommand\IG[2]{%
  \clipbox{#1\wd\myimg #1\ht\myimg #1\wd\myimg #1\ht\myimg}{%
  \includegraphics[decodearray={#2 1 #2 1},width=2in]{example-image-a.jpg}}}
\savebox\myimg{\IG{0}{0}}% FULL SIZED IMAGE FOR REFERENCE
\savestack\myimgA{\IG{.0750}{.00}}
\savestack\myimgB{\IG{.0625}{.17}}
\savestack\myimgC{\IG{.0500}{.34}}
\savestack\myimgD{\IG{.0375}{.51}}
\savestack\myimgE{\IG{.0250}{.68}}
\savestack\myimgF{\IG{.0125}{.85}}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\myimgA}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\myimgB}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\myimgC}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\myimgD}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\myimgE}{%
\myimgF%
}}}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I really like the improved version of your answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks, but with 50-100 images overlaid, the PDF loads **real slow**.  Clearly, this is still "sandbox" development.