# How to fade a shaded box

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to overlay a shaded transparent box on an image, to be able to write inside the box as in:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lblue}{RGB}{15,77,158}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,]{IMG_2124_Everest.jpg}};
    \shade [left color=lblue, right color=lblue, opacity=0.6] (-4,1) rectangle (4,2.5);
    \node[shift={(-0.0cm,1.73cm)}] at (0,0) { \textcolor{white}{\Huge\textbf{Mount Everest}} };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image from: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/IMG_2124_Everest.jpg]

and I would like to fade the border of the shaded box in order to decrease the visibility of the line that defines it.

I have read:

- [Tikz: faded node border has spurious extra border line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408956/tikz-faded-node-border-has-spurious-extra-border-line)
- [Including an image with a faded border](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222849/including-an-image-with-a-faded-border)

but I am lost on how to apply it to a shaded box. Is that even possible?

Image from: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/IMG_2124_Everest.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses a `foreach` loop to go from an inner rectangular box to an outer box with rounded corners. For other solutions, see linked questions in OP.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{9}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myheight}{3.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myfadewidth}{1}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
\foreach \i in {100,...,0}
\fill[transparent!\i, rounded corners=\myfadewidth/100*\i cm] (-\mywidth/2-\myfadewidth/100*\i+\myfadewidth,-\myheight/2-\myfadewidth/100*\i+\myfadewidth) rectangle (\mywidth/2+\myfadewidth/100*\i-\myfadewidth,\myheight/2+\myfadewidth/100*\i-\myfadewidth);
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {\includegraphics[width=12cm]{example-image}};
\node[
fill=blue, text=white, 
fill opacity=0.6, text opacity=1,
minimum width=\mywidth cm, minimum height=\myheight cm,
path fading=myfading, fit fading=false,
font=\Huge\bf,
yshift=1.5cm, fading transform={yshift=1.5cm},
] {Mount Everest};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: The text "Mount Everest" in a faded blue box on an example-image]

[image: The text "Mount Everest" in a faded blue box on image of Mount Everest]

Instead of a loop, a `\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading` could be used, but that is not simple and this warning is in the manual:

> These shadings are the least portable of all and they put the heaviest
> burden of the renderer. They are slow and, possibly, will not print
> correctly!