# How to give the shadow effect which is shown in the below image for the white rectangle in the code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, fill, shadows, shadowbox

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, positioning}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagecolor{blue!50}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\fill[fill=white]([xshift=23mm, yshift=-23mm]current page.north west)rectangle([xshift=-23mm, yshift=-227mm]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[[image: enter image description here][1]]

Comment: Maybe like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11272/47927

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagecolor{blue!50}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\fill[blur shadow={shadow xshift=5pt, shadow yshift=0pt, shadow blur radius=5pt},  white] ([xshift=23mm, yshift=-23mm]current page.north west)rectangle([xshift=-23mm, yshift=-227mm]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Top of a white rectangle with blurred shadow]

*Edit:*

Less pronounced shadow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagecolor{blue!20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\fill[blur shadow={shadow xshift=5pt, shadow yshift=0pt, shadow blur radius=5pt, shadow opacity=20}, white,
] ([xshift=23mm, yshift=-23mm]current page.north west)rectangle([xshift=-23mm, yshift=-227mm]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Top of a white rectangle with blurred shadow]

`shadows.blur` can not change color, but you can manually add a shadow like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagecolor{blue!20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\foreach \x in {0,0.025,...,1}
 \draw[blue!50, opacity=\x, thick] ([xshift=-23mm+10-10*\x, yshift=-23mm]current page.north east) -- ([xshift=-23mm+10-10*\x, yshift=-227mm]current page.north east);
\fill[white] ([xshift=23mm, yshift=-23mm]current page.north west)rectangle([xshift=-23mm, yshift=-227mm]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Top of a white rectangle with blurred blue shadow]

Comment: Is it possible to change the colour of shadow to blue anyway?

Comment: What do you mean by "anyway". A blue shadow on a blue background would not be visible. Do you want the shadow less dark?

Comment: Yees, actually I want the shadow less dark. I was referring the above image that I have attached and it has blue shadow which is less dark. And I also want to use the similar effect for my code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Vishakha: No need to write thank you on this site. It might sound strange, but it is actually discouraged to prevent clutter. Just upvote and accept answer.